# Windows ifort linker library path

Tags: windows, fortran, library-path, linker-flags, intel-fortran

Is there a possiblity (an environment variable or a flag) to tell the **Intel Fortran** linker

```
ifort ... mylib.lib
```

to search for libraries in a specified directory before searching the standard directories on Windows (similar to [-L](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525210) on Linux or `link`[/LIBPATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx) flag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ifort xxxx /link /LIBPATH:dir` to pass that option through to the linker, or add the directory to the the `LIB` environment variable.